# Put Let's Encrypt Certificate to API in Kong API Gateway?

Tags: api, ssl, gateway, kong

I'm keep getting error `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain` while trying to access one of my API. I'm using certificate from Let's Encrypt.

**Steps To Reproduce**

1. Get SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt which I got files
   `chain.pem`, `cert.pem`, `fullchain.pem`, `privkey.pem`
2. Add certificate object in kong using this command

   ```
   curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8001/certificates \
   -F "cert=@/path/to/cert.pem" \
   -F "key=@/path/to/privkey.pem" \
   -F "snis=subdomain.mydomain.com"
   ```
3. Try to access it using this

   ```
   curl -i https://mykongdomain.com/ \
   -H "Host: subdomain.mydomain.com"
   ```
4. Getting Error `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain`
5. I also have tried change the value of `cert` param using `@/path/to/chain.pem`, `@/path/to/fullchain.pem` but still got the same error.

Comment: Is the subdomain matching the certbot and did you try making the call from a rest client like postman?

Comment: did you find any solution ?